# Getting the filename of a resource when onClick

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I am going through android tutorials and android development websites. I came across the Gridview example here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html#example

In the example, on clicking on a imageview in the grid the position of the image in the GridView is displayed in a Toast message. Instead of the position of the Image, i would like to display the filename of the Resource (like if filename is sample1.jpg). How do I do that?

Thanks :)